# Printing formatted dictionary elements into a file

Tags: python

I have the following dictionary:

```py
sorted_dict = {'10': ('cola', '100', '1.0USD'), '2': ('shampoo', '300', '3.125USD'), '3': ('vaseline', '180', '10USD'), '4': ('chips', '150', '15USD'), '6': ('chocolate', '0', '20USD'), '1': ('tissue', '200', '30USD'), '5': ('cup', '0', '100USD'), '7': ('candy', '11', '135USD'), '9': ('lamp', '0', '220USD'), '8': ('juice', '15220', '1002USD')}
```

I want to write the contents of this dictionary to a text file in the following format:

```
10: cola, 100, 1.0USD
2: shampoo, 300, 3.125USD
...
```

I tried printing it using `file.write(str(sorted_dict))` but it converts as follows:

```py
{'10': ('cola', '100', '1.0USD'), '2': ('shampoo', '300', '3.125USD'), '3': ('vaseline', '180', '10USD'), '4': ('chips', '150', '15USD'), '6': ('chocolate', '0', '20USD'), '1': ('tissue', '200', '30USD'), '5': ('cup', '0', '100USD'), '7': ('candy', '11', '135USD'), '9': ('lamp', '0', '220USD'), '8': ('juice', '15220', '1002USD')}
```

How can I print out the contents of the dictionary in a way that matches the above format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over each key-value pair in the dictionary, and then write to the file while processing one pair at a time with a format string:

```py
with open('result.txt', 'w') as file:
    for key, value in sorted_dict.items():
        file.write(f"{key}: {', '.join(value)}\n")
```

Then, `result.txt` contains:

```
10: cola, 100, 1.0USD
2: shampoo, 300, 3.125USD
3: vaseline, 180, 10USD
4: chips, 150, 15USD
6: chocolate, 0, 20USD
1: tissue, 200, 30USD
5: cup, 0, 100USD
7: candy, 11, 135USD
9: lamp, 0, 220USD
8: juice, 15220, 1002USD
```

Answer (score -1):

```
file.write(str(sorted_dict)
```

So, lets read this code:

```
str(sorted_dict) # Equals to
sorted_dict.__str__()
```

so you are just writing to your `file` the `dict`ionary, without formatting it.

---

I would suggest something like this:

```
for key, value in sorted_dict.items():
    file.write(f"{key}: {value}\n")
```

Comment: yeah, it is very close, except i also want to remove the brackets around the value

Comment: Right, I had not read the question carefully enough, @BrokenBenchmark's answer should be accepted.